# Strange missing obj linker error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker

I'm attempting to bring over an old project to Visual Studio 2010 but I'm getting the following erorr on compile:

> Error 3   error LNK1181: cannot open input file
>   'Console\\.obj' C:\gizmo\Console\LINK   Console

The project is supposed to build out to a folder called 'Console'.

I've never encountered such an error before, could it have osmething to do with Visual Studio 2010 compatibility with visual studio 6?

Comment: Have a look at this thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/f99c5cea-c75e-4842-a64e-383851843999/

Comment: yep I did, doesn't help me though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would open the vcxproj file and check if there aren't any weird-looking paths in there.

Comment: yep that was the problem, it wasn't a weird path so much so it was looking for an environment variable or something that didn't exist .obj ($filename + .obj), since $filename was "" it was attempting to link up something with no name.